# Reflection API to create servlet object

Tags: java, servlets

Can somebody tell that how can I create a `Servlet` object using reflection api.
Please provide a proper document, except `Class.forName("some_class").newInstance()`.

Answer (score -1):

Since [`Class`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html) implements [`Type`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/reflect/Type.html) which is part of the reflection API, I'd say that

```
Servlet.class.newInstance();
```

would be a valid answer. But what on earth would you want to do that for...?

Cheers,